# Step initialization time too long using Partitioner in Spring-Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using `Partitioner` to parallelize the import of `*.csv` files. There are about 30k files in the folder.

Problem: the job initialization takes about 1-2h hours until all files are set up. The bottleneck is in `SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.split()`.

Question: is it normal that the step initializations require that much time? Or could I improve it somehow?

```
@Bean
public Step partitionStep(Partitioner partitioner) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionStep")
            .partitioner(step())
            .partitioner("partitioner", partitioner)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4); //run import always with 4 parallel files
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}


@Bean
public Partitioner partitioner() throws IOException {
    MultiResourcePartitioner p = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    p.setResources(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("mypath/*.csv"));
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`MultiResourcePartitioner` creates a partition for each resource. Partition creation process in itself is very fast ( i.e. partitioner returns the executioncontext map very fast) but Spring Batch takes huge time in populating corresponding meta data DB tables and it becomes terribly slow once number of partitions goes beyond 100 ( this is all my personal experience).

As per only answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366834/spring-batch-partitioning-performance-issue), they did some improvements but I am using latest version and its very slow for partitions more than 100.

See [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/122889-spring-batch-meta-data-table-insert-slowing-down-the-batch-job) too.

I think, you don't have much of a choice other than reducing number of partitions unless you are ready to rewrite a bunch of API code by yourself.

Comment: I'm using `spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false` and `MapJobRepository`, thus storing any metadata inmemory only. Anyways the "spring-batch stuff" around the batch job seem to slow it down (for my 30k files I'd have 30k partitions; but I have to stick to `Partitioner` as I have to define an outputfile name for each file based on the input). So probably I have to drop `spring-batch` here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom splitter because in the default splitter (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.java) , you call `jobRepository.getLastStepExecution` for each `StepExecution`. I don't use restartability with spring-batch, so i can write  my own splitter. Now step initialization takes few seconds for thousand of files (before it was few minutes)

Comment: This should be a comment